# Выражение "время оно"

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Насколько я понимаю, сейчас выражение "время оно" означает некую неопределенность с датами. То есть, "когда-то" или "некогда" (поправьте меня, если я ошибаюсь).
Но изначально такое выражение, по-моему, значило прямо противоположное - "то самое время" (если ничего не путаю, в Библии речь идет о Страшном Суде или Апокалипсисе).
Но хотелось бы узнать об этом выражении подробнее, а особенно о слове "***о***но" или "оное" (данное). Выходит, что оно происходит от местоимения среднего рода "он***о***", так?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы совершенно точно уловили значение "когда-то давно", "в те времена". Но это не изменённое значение, а изначальное. В древнерусском и старославянском языках это было указательное местоимение Оный (тот), а от него краткая форма всех родов и множ. числа Онъ, Она, Оно, Оны (ударение на О). Форма онъ восходит к праславянскому *оnъ, кот обозначало "тот" и "там". Вот эти два значения и слились - то, которое происходило там, когда-то.

Выражение это собственно библеизмом не считается, но евангелиями используется при повествовании о давних временах. Например, в Остромировом:

```
        1.Во время оно... рече папа к римлянам:
```

И сейчас во время богослужения чтение часто начинается со слов «Во время оно...», если проповедь начинается с повествования о деяниях святых и Бога в давние времена. Это  зачин, чтобы чтение не казалось вырванным из контекста.
Сегодня принято семь таких формул для Евангелия, в том числе:

1. Во время оно...
2. Во дни оны...

Comment: Исчерпывающий ответ @Людмила. Добавить нечего .

Comment: "...чтение часто начинается... если проповедь начинается" — чтение действительно  так часто начинается, особенно если это второй отрывок из Евангелия кряду, но о какой **проповеди** речь?

Answer (score 1):

Когда-то местоимение *он* было не личным, а указательным, и означало примерно "тот". Следовательно, *во время оно* == "в то время".

Answer (score 1):

Исходно в славянском было две группы указательных местоимений

Он (она, оно, оны) - имело значение "тот", "те";

И (Я, О, ИИ) - этот, эти.

Вторая группа использовалась еще и как местоимения личные (современные *он, она, они*, сохранились в косвенных падежах последних) и как артикли-послелоги (следы этого находим в современных полных прилагательных).

В результате грамматических изменений первая группа превратилась в личные местоимения, но сохранилась в выражениях типа "времена оны" = "в те еще времена". В любом случае ни к Апокалипсису, ни вообще к будущему неопределенному отношения не имеет.

Остальное - у Людмилы.

Answer (score 0):

У Матф. 8.18 есть выражение *Онъ полъ*, поясняемое Церк.-слав. словарём как «другая сторона, другой берег реки».

Оные времена = иные времена. В оные времена = когда-то.

Answer (score -1):

Помнится, читая один из текстов "Микре", я встретил выражение "время оно", что означало на древнееврейском не "те времена" и не "оные времена", а "время силы его". Потому что слово און- (он) мужская сила и (о) в конце - его. Источник-то, как сейчас любят говорить в России, изначальный, ещё не переосмысленный в старославянском варианте. Есть даже город в Израиле близ Тель-Авива, который и называется Кирьят-Оно, "город его силы". Есть имя: Лион, что значит - "мне силу".

Answer (score -1):

ών на древнегреческом  part. praes. к είμί быть

ών (8) Он (5), Которого (1), Он": (1), [земли] Он (1)
ων (86) будучи (47), являясь (11), который (1), пребывая: (1), Являющийся (13), Являющегося (1), являюсь (1), пребывающий (2), находясь (5), принадлежащий (1), находящаяся (1), Существующий (2)

https://manuscript-bible.ru/S/D/766E.htm#%u041An

Так что это может значить, «во времена былые» или "во времена праотцов" как значение (10) тут https://manuscript-bible.ru/S/D/6569.htm#e%u042Em%u042B

> 10. происходить, вести свой род (patrсw ¤j Ћgayoи Hom.; Ћpс tinow
>     Xen.): ¤k PaionЫhw eдnai Hom. быть родом из Пеонии; ¤k patrсw eЮmi
>     TelamЗnow gegЕw Soph. я - сын Теламона; aбmatow ЋgayoЭo ¦m(m)enai Hom.
>     быть знатного происхождения;

Релевантная цитата из Септуагинты Исход 3:14-15
https://manuscript-bible.ru/OT/Ex3.htm#14

Подстрочный перевод

> 14 Бог сказал Моисею: Я есмь Сущий [ών]. И сказал: так скажи сынам
> Израилевым: Сущий [ών] послал меня к вам. 15 И сказал еще Бог Моисею:
> так скажи сынам Израилевым: Господь, Бог отцов ваших, Бог Авраама, Бог
> Исаака и Бог Иакова послал меня к вам. Вот имя Мое на веки, и
> памятование о Мне из рода в род.

Бог ссылается на род и праотцов непосредственно в следующем предложении. Так что логично что "время oн[о]" - время бога праотцов/время праотцов.

Comment: Вы полагаете, что фонетического сходства с греческим словом совершенно другого значения и  даже являющимся другой частью речи достаточно для утверждения "так что это может может означать?"

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под "совершенно другого значения"? 
Если вы посмотрите принятый ответ, то он ссылается как раз на библию, я привел перевод соответствующего понятия из Септуагинты которая, насколько я знаю, была канонической для православной церкви. То, что это греческое слово использовано в русском, мне кажется совсем неудивительным.

Comment: Добавил ссылок и цитат чтобы обьяснить логические связки

Comment: Да при чем тут ссылки, простите? Я логики Вашей не понимаю - от слова совсем. Я рассчитывал на какое-то обоснование этимологии слова через вашу логику, но вы еще больше ушли в сторону "народной этимологии". И да, я читал "принятый ответ", не извольте сомневаться. Я даже ссылался на него.

Comment: *Так что это может значить* - не может. Фонетического сходства недостаточно для серьезного рассмотрения, а этимологического обоснования вы не даете.